# how to add new calculate array object to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
data = [
        {location: "Phnom Penh", sale: 1000 },
        {location: "Kandal", sale: 500 },
        {location: "Takeo", sale: 300 },
        {location: "Kompot", sale: 700 },
        {location: "Prey Veng", sale: 100 },
        {location: "Seam Reap", sale: 800 }
      ];
```

new calculate object :

```
Total1 = Phnom Penh + Takeo
```

```
Total 2 = Prey Veng + Seam Reap
```

then I want to add these two object to existing array (data)

```
data = [
        {location: "Phnom Penh", sale: 1000 },
        {location: "Kandal", sale: 500 },
        {location: "Takeo", sale: 300 },
        {location: "Kompot", sale: 700 },
        {location: "Prey Veng", sale: 100 },
        {location: "Seam Reap", sale: 800 },
        {location: "Total1", sale: 1300 },
        {location: "Total2", sale: 900 }
      ];
```

Anyone please help me to do like this? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Create 2 sum variables. Loop through the array and update the variables based on `location` values. Please add the code you've tried

Comment: After a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+to+array&oq=javascript+add+to+array) I found the [Array Push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a bespoke function that filters out the relevant objects, and then calculates their sum sales.

Here the data and an array of the locations is passed into `getSales`. The required objects are [filtered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out, and then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is used to sum their sales. You can then build a new object using the data from the old object, and adding in the new data.

```js
const data = [
  {location: "Phnom Penh", sale: 1000 },
  {location: "Kandal", sale: 500 },
  {location: "Takeo", sale: 300 },
  {location: "Kompot", sale: 700 },
  {location: "Prey Veng", sale: 100 },
  {location: "Seam Reap", sale: 800 }
];

function getSales(data, arr) {
  return data
    
    // Return the current object where the arr
    // includes the current object location
    .filter(el => arr.includes(el.location))

    // Iterate over those returned objects and sum their sales
    .reduce((acc, { sale }) => acc += sale, 0);
}

const out = [
  ...data,
  { location: 'Total1', sale: getSales(data, ['Phnom Penh', 'Takeo']) },
  { location: 'Total2', sale: getSales(data, ['Prey Veng', 'Seam Reap']) }
];

console.log(out);
```

Comment: May I suggest you one more. 
If I have another calculate object:

Total3 = Kompot - Seam Reap;
Total4 = Phnom Penh + Takeo + Kompot - Kandal + Seam Reap

Comment: If this helped you should probably accept it and then ask a new question. I won't have time to look at your new requirements, but someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the sales from the `4` locations and then [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the objects in the array. Something like this should work.

```
data.push({location: "Total1", sale: data["Phnom Penh"].sale + data["Takeo"].sale})
data.push({location: "Total2", sale: data["Prey Veng"].sale + data["Seam Reap"].sale})
```

Also note that `sale` may not be an integer and `+` may not add them, so you should use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).